# How get the title value in between of tag <li id="gridtag636894" class="tags" title="same">

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

Hi iam new to selenium webdriver some one help me how will get the title name 
Like in below code the (title name is same)

```html
<li id="gridtag636894" class="tags" title="same">
```

I tried below xpath

.//*[@class='tags']

Its place on that element fine but how i get the title name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code,

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.ByClassName("tags"));
for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++){

  String title=elements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
  System.out.println(title); 

}
```

*Note:I haven't compiled code*

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String title = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='tags']")).getAttribute("title");
```

To get all titles which has class `tags`:

```
Liss<String> titles = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='tags']")).getAttribute("title");
```

Note the difference between `findElement` and `findElements` in plural

Comment: When i try to add the list          List<WebElement> Case = dr
    .findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='tags']")).getAttribute("title");                 Its showing error on getattribute

Comment: Its possible store the title names to list, Its contains more title names in my page

Comment: @Rajkumar `getAttribute` returns String with the title name as you requested. You can't add it to list of WebElements

Comment: @Rajkumar I added solution for all titles with class `tags` to my answer

Comment: yea thats not working its showing error on getAttribute

Comment: @Rajkumar What is the error? what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope it helps.. :)

WebElement getValue = driver.findElement(By.id("gridtag636894"));

System.out.println(getValue.getAttribute("title"));